# Fortify - Trust Boundary Violation - ASP.Net Web Forms - Text-Box Form Fields

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, fortify

My project has 113 Trust Boundary Violations. Each violation is for any value stored to a session value. The values stored in the session are actually objects with several properties. So, each time a value is assigned to a property that is a violation. I can consider the values that are numbers as trusted since they are strongly typed as numbers. But, the strings that are coming from text-box form fields are confusing me. I do have ASP.Net Request Validation enabled.

The recommendation from Fortify says, "The untrusted data should be built up in a single untrusted data structure, validated, and then moved into a trusted location."

Does any further action need to be taken on the strings being set from text-box form fields in order for those values to be "validated"? Or, is the ASP.Net Request Validation sufficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the ASP.Net Request Validation is sufficient. When you mark it as false positive, the AI engine will learn it.

At the same time, I don't think it is a good practice to store several properties on session values.